# after drag and drop how do I save the new order in an array by using dragula?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Dragula for sorting and ordering some , but I need to get new order values into an array to save it through PHP.

I am using it through JQuery or Javascript.

```
    <div id="right-events" class="containerdrag">
     <div id="drag0" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2 ex-moved">choice1</div>
<div id="drag3" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2  ex-moved">choice4</div>
<div id="drag4" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2  ex-moved">choice5</div>
<div id="drag1" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2 ex-moved">choice2</div>
<div id="drag2" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2 ex-moved">choice3</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to output such an array :

```
$array = ("choice1","choice4","choice5","choice2","choice3");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get array of text values by using `map` and `get` jquery methods.

```js
$("#save").click(function() {
  const data = $('#right-events > div').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get()

  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="right-events" class="containerdrag">
  <div id="drag0" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2 ex-moved">choice1</div>
  <div id="drag3" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2  ex-moved">choice4</div>
  <div id="drag4" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2  ex-moved">choice5</div>
  <div id="drag1" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2 ex-moved">choice2</div>
  <div id="drag2" class="w-100 border border-primary rounded p-2 ex-moved">choice3</div>
</div>

<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: perfect solution